# Worth using sorted( ,key=) on a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm working on learning the ins and outs of Python's `sorted` function, and was wondering about sorting a data-structure like the following:

```
dict1 = dict(emp1={"Name": "McKay", "Job": "Developer"}, emp2={"Name": "Mandy", "Job": "Nurse"})
```

on either the 'Name' or 'Job' fields in the nested dictionary.  I've looked at some of the other results on this site, and it looks like it is at best messy, and at worst confusing and messy.  Is it generally recommended to not use this type of data structure if you want sorting?  (I know a tuple would be a better choice, but this is an academic question for my own curiosity).

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Let's say: emp1 name job\nemp2 name job (sorted by name or job)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you don't mind dealing with the sorted output being a *sequence* (dictionaries don't have any ordering), you can sort the contained key, values or key-value pairs just fine.

For example, to just get the nested dictionaries, sorted by name, is as simple as:

```
sorted(dict1.values(), key=lambda d: d['Name'])
```

This produces a sorted list with the 2 nested dictionaries as elements. The `key` function just needs adjusting based on what sorted output you require; for keys, you need to look up the associated value:

```
sorted(dict1, key=lambda k: dict1[k]['Name'])
```

Iteration over a dictionary produces keys, so all you need to pass to `sorted()` here is the dictionary itself.

Use `dict.items()` to produce a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs, and adjust the key again to extract the value-to-sort-on from that:

```
sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['Name'])
```

Demo with the latter:

```
>>> dict1 = dict(emp1={"Name": "McKay", "Job": "Developer"}, emp2={"Name": "Mandy", "Job": "Nurse"})
>>> for emp, info in sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['Name']):
...     print('{0}: {1[Name]} - {1[Job]}'.format(emp, info))
...
emp2: Mandy - Nurse
emp1: McKay - Developer
>>> for emp, info in sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['Job']):
...     print('{0}: {1[Name]} - {1[Job]}'.format(emp, info))
...
emp1: McKay - Developer
emp2: Mandy - Nurse
```